# Performance degration with remote debugger

Tags: java, performance, debugging, jvm, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug a server with remote debugger attached to its JVM. After opening the connection with JVM, I see that the server is slower then before. Is it because of remote debugging. Will remote debugger to JVM cause performance degradation?

Comment: You observe it yourself, so ... yes!

Answer (score 0):

According to this AMD article:
http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/articles-whitepapers/java-performance-when-debugging-is-enabled/

Yes